# isolated EJS Partial files loading to the browser, but not rendering on screen

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am loading my website with no errors in the console.
I have taken a static website (that used a little vanilla js for navigation), and tried ejs, templating out the menu page, header, footer, and a reused image path for promos that repeated throughout the website. I had success with this and wanted to repeat the process with the bulky blog section.

Ultimately, I had planned to refactor my blog partials into one template that could call blogs using node's 'fs' module, but my jam up has me at a loss.

**Q:Why is my page not completing its render, or rendering blank on two isolated areas of my code?**

Using NODEjs Express and EJS. Everything works as would be expected, except, the final blog and the contact form render blank.

I am only using to isolate blogs in their own ejs partial file:
`<%- include("../partials/blog0.ejs")%>`
The page will stop rendering at "blog3.ejs" and "contact" My vanilla js still operates by using the dom to `id.style.display="none" effectively`

I have deconstructed and un-nested my partials out of my index.ejs almost back to its original index.html. Everything Renders except for blog3 and contact.

index.js

```
const express =require('express');

const ejs = require('ejs');
const app = express();
var http = require('http');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var sass =require('sass');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('views'));
app.use(express.static('css'));
app.use(express.static('jsFiles'));
app.use(express.static('partials'));

//routes
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('pages/index');
  console.log('pages/index hit')
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('partial/header');
    console.log('partial hit')
})

app.set('view engine','ejs');
console.log('static site!! listening on:3005 started at: '+Date())
console.log('find app on: localhost:3005 ')
app.listen(3005);

http.createServer(function(req,res){
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
res.end('future api dev here');
}).listen(8080);
```

index.ejs

```
    <body onload="loader()">
    <%- include('../partials/burgerButton.ejs') %>
    <%- include('../partials/menu.ejs') %>
        <%- include('../partials/header.ejs') %>
   <div id="mainContent" class="content">


<!--each blog article. I had them in their own ejs file, but reversed that sonce experiencing my issue-->
  <div id="blogIntro" class="blogBody">
          <h1>Welcome to
              <span class="logoFont"> ValRick Travel's</span>
            featured Blogs</h1>
              

<div class="card">
*blog article*
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my old method using vanilla JavaScript was interfering with a display property = "none".

I removed id handlers in my scss and found EJS had been working exactly as I had programmed it.....to hide the  until the user called for it.

The error was in my jsFiles during migration from a static vanilla website over to express and ejs.